# Tableau incorrect average field value on drill up level

Tags: tableau-desktop, drilldown

I am very much new for tableau and working on a report in tableau with two level drill-down. I have three fields named 'Sales' and 'Quantity' and 'Avg-Price'. I need the correct value of 'Avg-Price' (**?**) when I drill-up on company level. See below picture

[image]

For field 'Avg-Price', I use 'CalculatedField' with formula '[Sales]/[Quanity]'.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SUM([Sales]) / SUM([Quantity])
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, simply wonder. its working....

Comment: You're welcome. This is called an aggregate calculated field, and is applied to groups of data records (determined by the dimensions in your viz) -- as opposed to a record level calculated field which is applied to each individual data record. Both are useful. See the Tableau help info for more explanation